# ORDER BY ASCENDING or NOT seems to it doesn't do anything

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm developing an Entity Framework 4.4.0.0 Code First library with C# and .NET Framework 4.0.

I have this code:

```
var messageQuery = (from message in context.Messages.Include("SentByUser").Include("SentToUser")
                    where message.TalkId == talk.TalkId
                    orderby message.DateUtcSent
                    select message).ToList();
```

And I test it with this one (I have added `ascending`):

```
var messageQuery = (from message in context.Messages.Include("SentByUser").Include("SentToUser")
                    where message.TalkId == talk.TalkId
                    orderby message.DateUtcSent ascending
                    select message).ToList();
```

**Both returns the result in the same order!!**

How can I do a select returning the older messages first?

`Message.DateUtcTime` is:

```
public DateTime DateUtcSent { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var messageQuery = (from message in context.Messages.Include("SentByUser").Include("SentToUser")
                    where message.TalkId == talk.TalkId
                    orderby message.DateUtcSent descending
                    select message).ToList();
```

Comment: I thought that descending doesn't exist on LinQ. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

`ascending` is the default behavior so adding it does not make a difference. It's `descending` that would return a different result.

Use the `descending` keyword to change the order of your result list.